# Put username to other activity with sharedpreference

Tags: java, android, session, authentication, sharedpreferences

I have value 'username' in MainActivity, get from login session.

How i can put this 'username' to other activity?

I use sharedpreference.

Can you help me? Pleasee

Comment: you can use intent.putExtra

Comment: [How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

To write the username:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("preferences", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putString("username", username);
editor.commit();
```

To get the username:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("preferences", 0);
String username = settings.getString("username", ""); //sets to "" if fails
```

Or you can pass it through the intent using a bundle:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("username", username);
Intent intent = new Intent(this, JoinChatActivity.class);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(this, NewActivity.class);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You are the best :) :)

Comment: No problem! Just make sure you mark an answer if one of these responses helped you, some of the people on here are pretty strict about it. Happy building!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**First you initialize the SharedPreferences in Top like this**

```
  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
```

**after that  get the value json like(username) and put the value SharedPreferences**

```
  username= obj1.getString("username");


 // Using shared preference storing the data in key value pair

     sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
     SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
     editor.putString("username", username);
     editor.apply();
```

**And get the value in next activity like this**

```
 SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
 String username= pref.getString("username", null);
```

**Pass the value in parameter like this**

```
  params.put("username", username);
```

i think it helps you

Comment: Thanks you so much. For your answer. It work and i can get value from MainActivity to other. :) :)

Answer (score 0):

Or you can transfer the value using Intent. for example:

This is MainActivity.class

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
Intent intent = new Intent (getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("userName", username);
getApplicationContext().startActivities(new Intent[] {intent});
}
```

Other.class

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_detail);
  Intent intent = this.getIntent();
  String username = intent.getExtras().toString("userName");
}
```